# Delete multiple rows across multiple sheets containing the same keyword

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have an excel file that contains around 50 sheets, all sheets have the same columns.

However, i would like to delete the entire rows that contains the same keyword `"MARTIN"` located in the 6th/last column in all the sheets.

I have tried to select all sheets at once and then delete the rows but it only worked for one sheet.

So if there is a way to do that either through an excel option or vba i'm all ears to suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    'Loop all sheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        With ws
            'Find the last row of column 6
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

            'Loop all rows in column 6 starting from the last one
            For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
                'If the value is "MARTIN" then delete
                If .Cells(i, 6).Value = "MARTIN" Then
                    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                End If

            Next i

        End With

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A quicker way to do it is to use shortcuts to delete the row and then go to the next sheet:

Say you want to delete the 6th row:

1. Go to the 6th row and hit `Shift+Space` this will highlight the entire row
2. To delete the row `Ctrl + -` (Ctrl and the minus sign)
3. Then to go from sheet one to sheet two you `Ctrl + Page Down btn`

If you really want to save time and know VBA you can create a short script. Unfortunately, I'm on my mac so I can't test one out right now but I found a good link that gives you a step by step [here](https://analysistabs.com/vba/delete-entire-row-excel-macro-code/)

Hope this helps!